# How to run/trigger javascript in controller action method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using .Net 4.0 and a lot of solution currently on the Internet are not working, for example non-exist library.

The whole story is: I have a main view, and within it there is 1 iframe. By clicking on the [submit] button on main view, it will trigger its own POST action as well as I make it trigger the POST of iframe by using javascript as follows:

```
function TriggerIframeAction() {
    var iframe = document.getElementById("myIframe");
    var iframeForm = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById("myIframeForm");
    iframeForm.submit();
}
```

However I need to make sure main frame's post always runs BEFORE iframe's post, so I am thinking to let main frame's action to trigger that JS.

I know Ajax.BeginForm(...OnSuccess...) may help. However it seems just mean the connection is successfully? If I put my validation code in main frame's action & make ModelState.IsValid = false, "OnSuccess" (so the iframe post) will still be executed which is not what I want ....

Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form id="form1" method="POST" action="/controller/action">

</form>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    var form = $('#form1'),
        url = form.attr('action'),
        formData = form.serialize();

    form.submit(function(){
        $.post(action, formData, function(result){
            if(result)
                TriggerIframeAction();
        })
        return false;
    }
});

function TriggerIframeAction() {
    var iframe = document.getElementById("myIframe");
    var iframeForm = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById("myIframeForm");
    iframeForm.submit();
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Action(FormCollection collection)
{
    // do something
    return Json(true);
}
```

Comment: sorry for possible errors in code, i have not tested it, but that's the idea how to do it